# why do quantum fields exist?

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, universe, big-bang, elementary-particles

Why did the big bang give rise to the quantum fields it did, could the big bang have created the universe any other way? and why not more elementary particles?

Answer (score 0):

The only theories I know of that connect the Big Bang to the “elementary” fields we see are theories in which there are extra spatial dimensions. The complicated geometry/topology of how these extra dimensions happened to curl up into microscopic size determined which “effective fields” exist our 4D world, and their interactions. For example, in string theory, all the particles and forces we know of may be determined by the shape of some tiny six-dimensional [Calabi-Yau space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) that we can’t detect. Geometry might explain the Standard Model!

This idea has been hard to realize because there are so many ways for the extra dimensions to compactify. This plethora of compactifications, combined with the possibility of cosmic inflation, has led to the speculation that compactification may happen differently in different universes within a multiverse, producing different particles and forces in different universes.

Hopefully a string theorist will provide a better answer.

Comment: good answer, it's interesting how the properties of the particles heavily depend on how the strings are vibrating, I don't research string theory so this has definitely got me more interested in the subject.